# 301 Redirect Error in .htaccess, shows "Bots Get Naked Version" instead of redirecting

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am looking to write 301 redirects for a site. I would like the redirect to go from http://www.ehlconsulting.com/our-services-basic-services/ to http://www.ehlconsulitng.com/services/.

My .htaccess file is as follow

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ehlconsulting.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.ehlconsulting.com/$1 [R=301,L]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
Redirect 301 /our-services-basic-services/ http://www.ehlconsulting.com/services/
```

When you go to the old URL it doens't redirect. Instead it shows "Bots get the naked version"

Comment: Great. Lets see some code...

Comment: FWIW, we just got this today too. Hosting at WPEngine, WP 3.8. Happens for any 404.

Comment: UPDATE: we found that string in WPEngine's plugin on github, so it was their issue. I got on with live support and the resolved the issue in about ten minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to use `Redirect` and want to move the actual redirect above your wordpress rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ehlconsulting.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.ehlconsulting.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^our-services-basic-services/(.*)$ http://www.ehlconsulting.com/services/$1 [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The "Bots get the naked version" thing doesn't have to do with your rules, it's probably WPEngine or something that's doing that by default, and you *might* be able to override that by using a `ErrorDocument 404` in your htaccess file. The problem with using a `Redirect` along with wordpress' `RewriteRule`'s is that they conflict with each other.